# Handling google's redirect uri on react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-api, react-router-dom

I currently have a React application which is using google OAuth. This is how it is being done right now:
Users navigate to google's url and login => google redirects the user to my app which uses google's code/token to do some stuff.

The problem is: google's code often contains unencoded slashes "/" and this is currently breaking react-router-dom and I have no idea how to deal with this situation.

@edit:
sample url `http://localhost:3000/google/?code=4/yA`

current Route: `<Route path="/google" {...} />`

ps.: I've already tried with "/google/*"

Comment: Can you paste sample url which contains slashes

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz just did it.

Comment: Sorry, what's the route that matches this. Paste so I'll update that in answer

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz just added it

Comment: this is strange, which version of react-router-dom are you using?

Comment: I tried and it worked

Comment: See this https://vvoqvk78.csb.app/schedule/?code=qwq/32